# How to get new data from server immediately in Android?

Tags: android, mysql, database, firebase-realtime-database, android-room

For the application I'm making, I have multiple devices that can all modify shared data on a server (My implementation currently uses Room to cache the data locally, Volley to handle http requests, and a PHP/MySQL database). When a user modifies the data, though, I want all other users to also have this up to date information.

So if user A were to modify the shared data like this...

```
[local data: 123] A----{{server data: 123}}----B [local data: 123]
[local data: 456] A----{{server data: 123}}----B [local data: 123]
[local data: 456] A->>-{{server data: 456}}----B [local data: 123]
```

How can I ensure that B gets the new data as quickly as possible? My current feeling is that I would just have to periodically query the server to see if there are any changes, but I wanted to make sure that this is "best practice." I don't know much about Firebase, but would that be good choice for this application?

Comment: Why don't you go with FDB (Firebase Real-time Database)!

Comment: I'm new to databases, and only have a MySQL db set up. I might try and switch to Firebase though

Comment: As @Radhey said use firebase real-time database.. And to use it you dont need to install anything just connect your app to firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase realtime database is meant for such use cases.
But you need you backend implementation in firebase too for that.

However,quick solution can be silent push notifications to devices from your backend, on receiving this devices can fetch new data from backend.

Comment: You mean I would have to have firebase installed on the server as well?

Comment: Yea, kind of. Actually your backend needs to be on Firebase, its a MBAS, mobile backend as service.